# How to find precise and clear info on whitespace requirements of a given lang, e.g., bash?

Tags: bash, whitespace

Langs have different whitespace requirements, e.g., python specifies very strictly how everything has to be spaced. If you could provide a general procedure for identifying these requirements from the manual or otherwise, that would be helpful. A specific example - bash - would be very helpful. This is the link to bash man: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual. You may quote from there to answer, but please also indicate how you looked for the info. This is the point - to find an efficient procedure to learn about a lang's whitespace requirements without knowing it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's special space requirements for bash. However there're places that space is obligated - e.g:

```
if [ "a$x" != "a" ]; then
      ...
fi
```

Writing ["a$x" without space after '[' won't work, since '[' is generally a link to *test* utility, so if no space after it bash will search for [a$x executable to execute. But this is special case. I don't think that bash has any more requirements regarding spaces.

There're few programming/scripting languages that use space/tab as an integral part of language.
For example makefile use tab for commands of rules:

```
target: prerequisite1 prerequisite2
     command1  # the line starts with tab
     command2  # the line starts with tab
```

Another language, which relies on spaces to understand the code, is as you mentioned is python.

Other langueages do not specify any space requirements, but for readibility you need to use indentation. All modern IDEs support help you automatically to indent the code. This group of languages is IMHO pretty big - C/C++/JAVA/bash/....

For example C code:

```
  int foo()
     {
          int i = 0;  // compiler do not need the spaces (indentation) in the beginning of the line,
                      // It is required for programmer to easy understanding the code.
          ...
          return i;
     }
```

You code write it as:

```
  int foo(){int i=0;return i;}
```

But there're other languages that have different syntax - e.g. html/sed/... where spaces have different meaning depending in which part of expression they are used.

Comment: Your answer was helpful by discussing bash specifics, categorising langs based on whitespace.

Comment: @user93200 Welcome to SO. It's ok to not accept any answer if there's no one which satisfies you :)

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, the whitespace is used as word separator. So in the bash manual, I would first search for "word". The first occurrence would lead me to the "Word splitting" section and there I'll encounter the `$IFS` and I'd dig further to see what that's about.

The Python example is not really the best you could choose, as in Python white spaces are used to define blocks of code, so white space plays an important role in the language syntax, besides being a word separator.

If you want to get to the roots of a topic like this one (as a side note, I don't really see why white space would be more interesting than parentheses or any other symbols), just look for the grammar definition of the language that you're interested in and see what role the symbols you're tracking are actually playing.

You will rarely find explicit "whitespace requirements" about some language, but you'll find a lot of syntax requirements (that may involve lots of whitespace contraints -- like in Python -- or a lot of parentheses constraints -- like in Lisp).

Comment: Your answer was helpful by addressing the procedure you performed to answer bash question and by comparison with lisp. The general procedure of examining the grammar definition makes sense. The only difficulty is that the grammar may be phrased or organised so as to make understanding difficult.  
 
I find the two answers so far given satisfying, and they each have their merits, so I won't put one above the other by accepting either.